# Sobolev embedding on the torus

Tags: partial-differential-equations, reference-request, sobolev-spaces

Does anyone have a reference on where to look up Sobolev spaces and Sobolev embedding on the $d$-dimensional torus instead of euclidean space?
In particular, I am interested in the embedding
\begin{align*}
H^s \hookrightarrow C^k_b
\end{align*}
which is perfectly clear to me in the euclidean case.

Thank you already for your answers.